# Defining a left-to-right parser for arithmetic expressions

Tags: parsing, haskell, arithmetic-expressions, left-to-right

I'm having a hard time defining a left-to-right arithmetic expression parser in Haskell. What I have done so far is defining a right-to-left parser, following the "G. Hutton, Programming in Haskell" book.

```
-- the aexpr integer parser
aexpr_int :: Parser Int
aexpr_int = do
              a1 <- aterm_int
              s <- sign -- return 1 for "+" and -1 for "-"
              a2 <- aexpr_int
              return (a1 + (s * a2))
            <|>
            aterm_int

-- the aterm integer parser
aterm_int :: Parser Int
aterm_int = do
              a1 <- aterm_int
              char '*'
              a2 <- afactor_int
              return (a1 * a2);
            <|>
            do
              a1 <- afactor_int
              char '/'
              a2 <- aterm_int
              return (div a1 a2)
            <|>
            afactor_int

-- afactor_int
afactor_int :: Parser Int
afactor_int = do
                token (char '(')
                e <- aexpr_int
                token (char ')')
                return e
              <|> 
              do
                s <- sign 
                ic <- aexpr_int 
                return (s * ic)
              <|>  
              token int_const
```

So this parses `1 - 2 - 3 - 4` as `1 - (2 - (3 - 4))`, but I want it to parse as `((1 - 2) - 3) - 4`. How can I reach this result?

Comment: Regardless of programming language: you should never write comments that merely repeat what the name and/or signature already say.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Yeah, I know. That was a mere placeholder because I was testing and I always add comments. The other parsers have appropriate comments.

Comment: https://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis552/15fa/lectures/Parsers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick here is to define an `aexpr_int` parser that first parses an `aterm_int`, and then *recursively*, using a helper function on an accumulating expression, checks for multiple additional occurrences of `sign >> aterm_int`, adding the additional terms to the accumulator.  It might look something like this:

```
-- the aexpr integer parser
aexpr_int :: Parser Int
aexpr_int = do
  a1 <- aterm_int
  go a1
  where go expr =
          do
            s <- sign
            a2 <- aterm_int
            go (expr + (s * a2))
          <|> return expr
```

Together with the following:

```
-- the aterm integer parser
aterm_int :: Parser Int
aterm_int = do
  a1 <- afactor_int
  go a1
  where go expr =
          do
            char '*'
            a2 <- afactor_int
            go (expr * a2)
          <|>
          do
            char '/'
            a2 <- afactor_int
            go (div expr a2)
          <|> return expr

-- afactor_int
afactor_int :: Parser Int
afactor_int = do
                token (char '(')
                e <- aexpr_int
                token (char ')')
                return e
              <|>
              do
                s <- sign
                ic <- afactor_int
                return (s * ic)
              <|>
              token int_const
```

this seems to work correctly:

```
> parseTest aexpr_int "1-2-3-4"
-8
```

Note that, if you're using a real parser library instead of trying to write your own parser code for learning purposes, you'll want to use the library's built-in expression parser or combinators with names like `chainl` or `sepBy` to accomplish this.